# Probability tree problem

Tags: probability

5) Diseases A and B are prevalent among people in a certain population. It is assumed 
that 14% of the population will contract disease A sometime during their lifetime, 9% 
will contract disease B eventually, and 3% will contract both diseases.

I am trying to think of this using trees. Would there be 3 variables for the first set of nodes one for each case? Assuming that this is out of 100.

Would be it something like this?

```
   /     |       |     \
14       9       3     74
```

Comment: You didnt specify what is the question asking?

Comment: 5a) Find the probability that a randomly chosen person from this population will contract 
at least one disease. 
 
5b) Find the conditional probability that a randomly chosen person from this population 
will contract both diseases, given that he or she has contracted at least one disease. 
 
5c) Find the probability that a randomly selected person from this population will not 
contract any diseases.

Comment: you cant use trees in this, as some population is common to contracting both the diseases, better use sets and union of sets, or inclusion-exclusion principle. I can give the answer if you want, but not from the tree method.

Comment: @abstractnature I was hesitant about using a tree because it doesn't make much sense. Could you please explain what you got?

Comment: here you go, i have given the answer using inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let set $A$ contains 14 percent population that will contract disease A, set $B$ contains 9 percent population that will contract disease B

it is given that $|A \cap B| = 3\%$

Using inclusion-exclusion principle, we have,

Population that will contract atleast one disease is = $|A\cup B| $

$= |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$

$14 + 9 - 3 = 20\%$

So, 20 percent people will contract atleast one of the disease,

5a. Probability that randomly choosen person will contract atleast one of the disease = $$20/100 = \frac{1}{5}$$

5b. conditional probability that a randomly chosen person from this population will contract both diseases, given that he or she has contracted at least one disease

Now the sample space has been reduced to 20percent of population only,

so, $$P((A \cap B)|(A \cup B))= \frac{3}{20} $$

5c. $$1 - P(A \cup B) = \frac{4}{5}$$